# Discrepancy in simplification

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For the below mentioned

```
simplify[(1/x)*(t/x)^(N-1)*(1-(t/x)^N)^(-2)]
```

and

```
simplify[(1/x)*(t/x)^(N-1)*(-1+(t/x)^N)^(-2)]
```

I am getting the same output which is

```
(t/x)^N/(t (-1 + (t/x)^N)^2)
```

How is it possible? Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because It is about math, not programming.

Comment: Should be on Mathematica SE site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only terms that are different in your "code" are

```
(1-(t/x)^N)^(-2)
```

and

```
(-1+(t/x)^N)^(-2)
```

and these are identical too. It's because the parentheses that are raised to the power of -2 are negatives of each other. A power of something to -2 is equal to 1 over the power the same thing to 2 and, as you certainly know, `x^2` is equal to `(-x)^2`.

Proof: just perform the exponentiation. Let `B = (t/x)^N` (so that I don't need to write it over and over again). The first expression:

```
(1 - B)^(-2) = 1 / ((1 - B)^2) = 1 / (1 - 2*B + B^2)
```

And the second expression:

```
(-1 + B)^(-2) = (B - 1)^(-2) = 1 / ((B - 1)^2) = 1 / (B^2 - 2*B + 1) = ...
... = 1 / (1 - 2*B + B^2)
```

Proved.

If we were to substitute back for the `B` then the result is

```
1 / ((t/x)^2N - 2*(t/x)^N + 1)
```